# Keras ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory for segmentation with numpy array as image type

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am using `ImageDataGenerator` with flow_from_directory for a segmentation task.

Folders are structured as:

> ```
> >      MyData/TrainImages/Train/image001.npy
> >      MyData/TrainMasks/Train/image001.npy
> >      MyData/ValImages/Val/image002.npy
> >      MyData/ValMasks/Val/image002.npy
> ```

I run:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
     #augmentation stuffs...)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
     #ditto...)

train_image_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     'MyData/TrainImages/',
     batch_size = BS)
train_mask_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     'MyData/TrainMasks/',
     batch_size = BS)

val_image_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     'MyData/ValImages/',
     batch_size = BS)
val_mask_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     'MyData/ValMasks/',
     batch_size = BS)

train_generator = zip(train_image_generator, train_mask_generator)
val_generator = zip(val_image_generator, val_mask_generator)
```

but receive as output:

> ```
> Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.
> Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.
> Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.
> Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.
> ```

I've googled around but most answers point to folder structure and I think mine is correct. Is this because my images are stored as numpy arrays rather than an expected format (jpg, png, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory):

> Any PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator.

So it will not try to load `.npy` files. Luckily, it should be relatively easy to implement your own data generator. Simply get a list of all the files in a directory, select files in a random order, load them with numpy, and `yield` them.

Comment: Yup you're right. And I did mess up the folder structure on top of it. With folder structure corrected but leaving numpy arrays you get 0 images in 1 class (edited in post)

Comment: I'm new to keras/tf so maybe a dumb questions, but I'm doing a fair amount of augmentation (rotation, shear, etc.) with the ImageDataGenerator, is there a simple way to build the custom generator with all these same attributes?

Comment: @user3470496 Create a standard `ImageDataGenerator`, and then use its `random_transform` function on each image that you generate. See [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/28b8c9a57703b60ea7d23a196c59da1edf987ca0/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py#L146) for how they are doing it. (`random_transform` is just a shortcut for `get_random_transform` and `apply_transform`.)